# What are the advantages of openID over browserID?

Tags: web-services, authentication, openid, browserid

I am currently working on a webapp and am wondering about the trade-offs of using browserID vs OpenId.

It seems to me that many more users have accounts with google or facebook than with browserID, so it might be easier for them to login. On the other hand some people don't like logging in with their credentials on some other sites for privacy reasons.

The account creation / login flow in browserID is arguably more similar to the traditional username/password login so there might be a lower barrier to entry for some users.

In my first iteration, should I ditch everything and just use browserID? Use openID as well, or go all out and use all three methods of authentication straight away?

Comment: dunno why this was closed, voted for reopen.